# Setting WPF Button background to text

Tags: wpf, button, wpf-controls

I'd like to have a button with text at the bottom, but more text in the background, specifically from a UI font. That way the content text at the bottom can be seen over the background.

It doesn't seem like StackPanels and DockPanels help as they always allocate room for each control so they don't overlap.

Something like:

```
<Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol">
  <Button.Background>
    <TextBox Text="" Foreground="White" Background="#FF5B9BD5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0"/>
  </Button.Background>
  <TextBox Text="Text" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0"/>
</Button>
```

This code does not work as the Background does not support controls, only Brushes.

Comment: there is `VisualBrush`. and controls in `Grid` panel can overlap. not sure I understand your desired layout, screenshot can help

Comment: I think it is a Grid that I want. Desired layout is content text at the bottom, centred, and "background" text in the centre of the button, also centred.

Comment: Thanks, I got it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a grid achieves this:

```
<Button VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontStretch="Expanded" BorderThickness="0">
  <Grid>
    <TextBox Text="" Foreground="White" Background="#FF5B9BD5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="36" BorderThickness="0"/>
    <TextBox Text="Text" Foreground="White" Background="#FF5B9BD5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" BorderThickness="0"/>
  </Grid>
</Button>
```